# receive and parse mails on the server via php

Tags: php

maybe mine it's a bit a simple question;
I would like to instruct my server to receive mails and to parse them via a php script. 
How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: I think this belongs to superuser.com. In any case, you probably wanna set up a procmail entry to automatically call a PHP script when you receive a mail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Process incoming emails with script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466256/process-incoming-emails-with-script)

Comment: Ehm, thank you for your answer, but I'm really a non pro, especially at server settings. Which one is the simplest solution? the best for me would be to use an external service that manage all the mail stuff and than call my script passing the mail components as GET or POST input every time a new one arrives!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email is going to be sent to an email address that you chose.  The email will be stored on either a POP3 or IMAP server and you will have to periodically poll the server to check for new messages.  If new messages are detected, your app will then have to download and parse them, and then delete the message from the server.

There are a handful of classes / code snippets out there that will do most of the heavy lifting for you. (like [this example](http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4015.html)).  You'll probably want to configure the script to be executed via a cron job so it runs every 5 minutes or-so.

As a side note though, using PHP for this application is rather inelegant.  PHP is designed to render HTML and interact with a user.  Using a more general purpose language like Python or Perl would be a better solution.

Comment: Or you can just have the MTA feed the email to a script, much as is described in the question that this one is a duplicate of.

Comment: the problem is that I'm not the administrator of the server and I have really little permissions on it (not to speak of knowledge). That's why I was hoping to lean on an external mail service.