# request system via e-mail

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron, request

I need to create a service for a website.
It's a request system via e-mail: writing a message to an e-mail server, this will generate an action.

**For example**: when writing with subject *mysecretpassword* to the e-mail address `reboot@midominio.com`, it will run the command reboot on the server.

I thought of several possibilities.

- Creating a service to interpret the MTA request and delegate it to a PHP interpreter, etc...
- Use Postfix and save the e-mails in MySQL and a *cron* reader
- Use a conventional mail server and use a *cron* to launch a PHP script that access the POP3/IMAP server and read the mailbox.

See: Which of these options is the most interesting?
Do you know any open source project like to get ideas for the code?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds way to dangerous to me. if you can email the server why cant you log in to the server? there is no security with email every admin on every server it passes through could compromise you.

Comment: I intend to do things like:
when an user receives a private message in my website, it sends a notification to the user via e-mail with the message, and the user receives an email from the address 'MD5Hash' @ mydomain.com, the user can reply directly to this e-mail to make a request to php and this makes a php application running on

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to do it is to create a [pipe alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2466271/20862), and then read and decode the message from stdin in the script.